# Recreate a webpage from browser cache

Tags: google-chrome, browser, website, browser-cache

I visited a webpage yesterday using Chrome. That website no longer exists. I checked the browser cache, and I see something along the lines of this (just a lot more of it)

```
00000000:  1f  8b  08  00  00  00  00  00  00  03  b4  53  4d  6f  db  38  ...........SMo.8
00000010:  10  bd  e7  57  30  bc  34  01  64  c9  b2  1d  db  b5  2d  03  ...W0.4.d.....-.
00000020:  49  da  1c  7a  48  0b  6c  f6  50  04  41  30  a2  46  16  13  I..zH.l.P.A0.F..
00000030:  99  14  48  4a  8a  ea  fa  bf  ef  48  f6  6e  bc  6e  b0  d8  ..HJ.....H.n.n..
00000040:  1e  72  90  34  9f  ef  cd  8c  66  16  a7  9f  be  5e  df  7d  .r.4....f....^.}
00000050:  ff  f6  99  65  6e  9d  2f  17  fb  37  42  b2  5c  58  61  64  ...en./..7B.\Xad
00000060:  e1  98  6b  0a  8c  b8  c3  17  17  3c  41  05  3b  2b  5f  9e  ..k......<A.;+_.
00000070:  04  c1  e2  f4  fe  fa  d3  e5  dd  e5  fd  89  33  cd  46  a6  ............3.F.
```

Is there any way to reconstruct the website from this? I just need some text that was on there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your browser may have a "Work Offline" option, and you may be able to select the webpage from
your browsing history list and have it displayed. If not, there are third-party utilities
that can display the cache contents from the various browsers. A good one for Chrome is offered
by Nirsoft Software at http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cache_view.html. I shudder at the
thought of using a hex editor to extract text, which is probably UTF-8 encoded.